# outlook addin inserting multiple entries into the local db

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm developing an outlook add-in which has dropdowns for category and sub-category.On the click of send button,details such as Sender,Receiver,Cc,BCc,Subject,category,sub-category(from the dropdown)are inserted into a local db.However,often multiple entries are getting inserted on the click of a single send button.In the code given below,on the click of the send button,the current as well as the previously selected items are getting displayed in the messagebox. 
Can anyone help me with this??

```
application.ItemSend += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    string cat = dropDown1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(cat);
 }
```

the code for populating the dropdown is given below:

```
 OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            string str1 = "select cat from category";
            com = new OleDbCommand(str1, con1);
            OleDbDataReader reader1 = com.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader1.Read())
            {
                RibbonDropDownItem item = Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonDropDownItem();
                item.Label = reader1["cat"].ToString();
                dropDown1.Items.Add(item);
            }
            con1.Close();
            reader1.Close();
```

Comment: Hod did you fill the drop down list with items? What code do you use for setting the selected item of the drop down control?

Comment: So what is your code inserting the data? Does your ItemSend event handler fire multiple times for a single Send button click? Keep in mind that the sender related properties are not yet filled in by the time ItemSend event fires.

Comment: yes... data insertion happens once only the first time.then twice,thrice and so on

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you subscribe to the ItemSend event of the Application class multiple times. Where and when do you subscribe to the ItemSend event?